# importing psutil into web2py: "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py, psutil

I am developing a web app using web2py. In my Python code, I have to use psutil for calculating the disk size, RAM being used, free RAM, and related information.

I have installed on my system psutil-2.1.1 for Python 2.7, and so far I had no problem with psutil.
But when I import psutil into my web2py application, I get an import error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from psutil._common import memoize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\_common.py", line 12, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
 ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I understand that the error means I am trying to import a 32bit-something into a 64bit-something or viceversa. Independent of web2py, psutil works just fine. I've tried running the same in a virtual environment also, and it gives the same error. As far as I know, web2py has no explicit separate installer for 32bit and 64bit, so I don't understand where the problem lies.

You can find the code where I've had to use psutil below:

```
#all necessary imports
import psutil

def summ_handler():
    #...
    disk_size = float (psutil.disk_usage(curr_dir).total)/(1024**3)
    print ("System Space                     : %sGB " %disk_size)

    #...
    ram_total = float(psutil.phymem_usage().total)/(1024**3)
    ram_free  = float(psutil.phymem_usage().free)/(1024**3)
    ram_used = ram_total - ram_free
    #printing

    #...
```

Edit:
I have included the differences in `sys.path` here

1. `sys.path` from `web2py`

`C:\Python27\web2py\site-packages
C:\Python27\web2py
C:\Python27\web2py\gluon
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.4.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\web2py\library.zip
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
C:\Python27\web2py\gluon`

2. `sys.path` for an ordinary script. `psutil` works here.

`C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.4.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg
C:\windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info`

Comment: Do you both 32-bit Python and 64-bit Python installed on your system? Which one does `web2py` use?

Comment: No, i just have 64 bit installed, checked now. Web2py uses this itself.

Comment: How have you installed `web2py`, from source or via its binary distribution? Were there any errors reported during its installation? Does `web2py` work smoothly when `psutil` is not imported?

Comment: I installed web2py via source, no errors during installation. Yes, it works fine without psutil. Independent of each other, web2py and psutil work fine, but not when I import psutil into my app.

Comment: Have you installed [Mark Hammond's win32 extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)?

Comment: Um.. I installed pywin32 - build 219, it hasn't made any difference. What exactly is the purpose of these win32 extensions?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the 64 bit build of [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)?

Comment: Yes, I installed pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7.exe from here - http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

Comment: This is pretty far-fetched, but is `C:\python27\DLLs` in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but `sys.path` is the `PYTHONPATH`, isn't it? And, `C:\Python27\DLLs` is in my `sys.path`

Comment: It's [not exactly the same](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path), but since it's already in your `sys.path`, it won't make an impactful difference. Try printing `sys.path` once from `web2py` and once from an ordinary script that successfully imports `psutil` and see what differences are there.

Comment: I've edited the question to show you the differences. Is the reason that `web2py` doesn't show up in the `sys.path` for the ordinary script the cause? Also, someone pointed out that the license maybe an issue. Is that a probable cause?

Comment: I don't think it's the license. It is one of paths that appear in the ordinary script's `sys.path` but not in `web2py` one's. Try appending each of them to `sys.path` in `web2py` before importing `psutil` and see which one makes a difference.